# My UserClaimsPrincipalFactory does not generate claims during login. (Dotnet 6.0.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, claims, userprincipal

I am trying to build a login system combining Microsoft.Identity and AzureAD login integration. Currently, the user is able to login with their Microsoft account through the AD portal, but during this process my customized UserClaimsPrincipalFactory is never reached (I've checked with breakpoints during debugging with Visual Studio 2022, and checked the data from the results of the login).

My current setup is as following:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<IdentityRole, UserAppContext>>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserClaimsFactory>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserAppContext>();
```

I have also tried to not use "AddClaimsPrincipalFactory" or any add function besides "AddEntityFrameworkStores()" and initialize them through AddScoped instead, but the result remains the same.

My UserClaimsPrincipalFactory looks as following

```
public class ApplicationUserClaimsFactory: UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserClaimsFactory(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {

    }
    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
 
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("Test", "true")
        };
        identity.AddClaims(claims);
        return principal;
    }
    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claims = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        claims.AddClaim(new Claim("name", "Aris"));
        claims.AddClaim(new Claim("Test", "true"));
        return claims;
    }
}
```

Nothing I've tried using UserClaimsPrincipalFactory works. I've been able to assign new claims using the IClaimsTransformation interface, but I want to be able to pull data from a database and use that data to determine which claims to assign a given user.